# DarkUI DarkTreeView and DarkListView scroll issues

Tags: scroll, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel, vertical-scrolling

DarkUI is powerful Dark themed control and docking library for .NET WinForms (https://github.com/RobinPerris/DarkUI).
Although, the DarkTreeView and DarkListView controls have strange behaviour on scroll actions.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What's the question? Or is this some sort of spam / self-advertisement?

Comment: Hello @matt, the DarkTreeView and DarkListView controls have strange behaviour on scroll actions, and this answers the issue.

Comment: Then it doesn't go in the Question field. The Question field is for a _question._ If you want to give an answer, you put it  in the Answer field. It is fine to put both a question and an answer, but the question must be a question and the answer must be an answer.

Comment: Hope you like it now :D

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the UpdateThumb method into DarkScrollBar.cs to:

```
private void UpdateThumb(bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    // Calculate size ratio
    float maxsize = (float)((Minimum < Maximum) ? (Maximum - Minimum) : (Maximum - Minimum));
    if (maxsize == 0)
        _viewContentRatio = 1.0f;
    else
        _viewContentRatio = (_scrollOrientation == DarkScrollOrientation.Vertical) ? (Height / maxsize) : (Width / maxsize);
    
    var viewAreaSize = Math.Max(maxsize, 1);
    var positionRatio = ((float)Value - Minimum) / (float)viewAreaSize;
    if (Minimum < 0)
    {
        positionRatio = (float) ((Minimum*-1) + (float) Value)/(float) viewAreaSize;
    }

    // Update area
    if (_scrollOrientation == DarkScrollOrientation.Vertical)
    {
        var thumbSize = (int)(_trackArea.Height * _viewContentRatio);
        _thumbArea = new Rectangle(_trackArea.Left + 3, _trackArea.Top + (int)(_trackArea.Height * positionRatio),
            Consts.ScrollBarSize - 6, Math.Max(thumbSize, Consts.MinimumThumbSize));
    }
    else
    {
        var thumbSize = (int)(_trackArea.Width * _viewContentRatio);
        _thumbArea = new Rectangle(_trackArea.Left + (int)(_trackArea.Width * positionRatio), _trackArea.Top + 3, 
            Math.Max(thumbSize, Consts.MinimumThumbSize), Consts.ScrollBarSize - 6);
    }

    if (forceRefresh)
    {
        Invalidate();
        Update();
    }
}
```

And changed OnMouseWheel into DarkScrollBase.cs to:

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    const int offset  = 50;
    var horizontal = false;

    if (_hScrollBar.Visible && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        horizontal = true;

    if (_hScrollBar.Visible && !_vScrollBar.Visible)
        horizontal = true;

    if (!horizontal)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
            _vScrollBar.ScrollBy(-offset);
        else if (e.Delta < 0)
            _vScrollBar.ScrollBy(offset);
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
            _hScrollBar.ScrollBy(-offset);
        else if (e.Delta < 0)
            _hScrollBar.ScrollBy(offset);
    }
}
```

You can also change the scroll speed by changing the offset value.